# Excel VBA code to upper case all cells

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, excel-2010, vba

Goal:
The goal is to gain the result from the picture below

[image]

Problem:
The current situation is below

How should I do it in order to gain the result in the goal by using VBA code.

[image]

Comment: You just want to `uppercase` the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub sample()
 Range("B4:E7") = [index(upper(B4:E7),)]
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Would you care to explain your syntax? Why use `index`? And why the `,)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("C4:F7")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = UCase(cell)
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers make you include a range. This works if you're talking about all cells.

```
sub EverythingToUpperCase()
   For Each Cell in ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        Cell.Value = UCase(Cell.value)
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

shortest versions i have seen:

With Target                     '(end with at bottom)

```
    Target = UCase(Target)    'Ucase  or  Lcase

    'Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)    '<< PROPER
```

AND..  Thee 1 Liner ?:

```
    Selection.Value = UCase(Selection.Value)  'YES  <<  1 LINER UCASE  (tested, worked),  add a range
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread, but was looking for something that would Uppercase only the cells I selected (Horizontal, vertical, selected cells with gaps, or any combination). Finally made something that works for me that I put on the ribbon and with a drag select cells, click macro button gets all caps! (If needing entire worksheet caps, there is better methods like UsedRange, but for just a specific small selected range this works great). For the original example I would drag select B4:E7 then click the ribbon macro button "All_Caps" and the rest of the worksheet would stay unchanged.

```
Sub All_Caps()
 
Dim rng As Range

Dim cell As Range

Dim addr As String
    
addr = Selection.Address

Set rng = Range(addr)
    
For Each cell In rng

  cell.Value = UCase(cell)

Next cell

End Sub
```